# Solving N queries on array on N elements in linear time O(N)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of n elements. ‘n’ operations needs to be performed on the array. For each operation start_index, end_index,trim_value is given. One has trim the value starting from the start_index to end_index inclusive. If the value at that index is more than or equal to trim value then make it equal to trim_value else leave it as it is. After performing ‘n’ operations find the maximum value of the array.
Is it possible to solve this problem in linear time. I came up with at least O(nlogn) approach. But It was asked to solve in linear time.

Comment: Show us your findings? At least post your O(n log n) solution.

Comment: And the operations are not sorted in any way already? ( by start_index or by trim_value )

Comment: No its not sorted already.But Since start_index is from 1 to n. you can sort it in linear time.But to sort operation by trim_value it takes NlongN.Because range is not defined for trim_value.

Comment: Please give us an example!!!! Your English is not clear...

Comment: I think noone is able to solve this problem. Its very hard or what ?